# MPFR, printf, decimal places, locales, file i/o problem

Tags: c, internationalization, floating-point, locale

A user of my program has reported problems reading a settings file written by my program. I looked at the settings file in question and instead of decimal points using the period "`.`" it uses commas "`,`".

I'm assuming this is to do with locales?

The file i/o is using `fprintf` and `mpfr_out_str` for file output and `getline` combined with `atol`, `atof`, `mpfr_set_str`, etc for file input.

What do I do here? Should I force my program to always use periods even if the machine's locale wants to use commas? If so, where do I start?

Edit: I've just noticed that this problem occurs when specifying the settings file to use on the command line instead of loading it via the GUI - would this indicate a problem on the OP's machine or in my code?

Comment: I have the feeling that mpfr is not responsible for localization of the floating point printout...

Comment: Yes, I get that feeling too, as all floating point values output, regardless of whether mpfr or printf routines were used, are the same.

Comment: what happens if you run the program after export LC_ALL=C ?

Comment: I can't personally test this as the problem occurs on a user's machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you call `setlocale` at all? If not, I would suggest either embedding the locale used to generate the file in the settings file **or** force all settings file I/O to use the C locale, via the previous suggestion of `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C")`.

One other option is to use the locale specific formatting functions (suffixed with `_l` in MSVC) and create the C locale explicitly, via `_create_locale(LC_ALL, "C")`.

Comment: Ah, sorry forgot to mention Linux. Nevertheless, `setlocale` is C89... Is forcing C locale acceptable application behaviour?

Comment: I could apply the C locale only to numeric formatting like so `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C")`.

Comment: I have accepted this answer finally, but not without further investigation. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171527/how-do-i-remove-the-difference-in-locale-between-gui-and-commandline-interfaces-o

Comment: Yes, well, ideally you'd go and store this data out without using locale specific formatting (i.e., not text), but that's probably an entirely different question.